# Can I get VendorID, ProductID via Bluetooth from device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I connect to device via bluetooth. I use BluetoothDevice.class an get mac address and name.
But I have to know VendorID, ProductID. It is possibla on iPhone.
There are any solution for Android for get it?

Answer (score 2):

Check this [official BT specification details](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFkQFjAE&url=https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=41500&ei=Y2EoUszAL-Gd7QbjvIHYBg&usg=AFQjCNFUpTKtM8BQjYUZ5NIr_5-GYx_sFA&sig2=QnJCduukol4DWoWQjSF01Q&bvm=bv.51773540,d.ZGU) to understand how you can do it..

On Page 10 :

> "The DI Service Record attributes are listed below.."

..you will find table followed by detailed specification.